# Unable to boot Oracle Linux in Virtual Box

Tags: oracle-linux, oracle-database, oracle, oracle-vm-server

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

I'm trying to install Oracle Linux 8.1. It works but then the reboot needed after the installation takes it back to the installation screen.
It basically does not boot into the Oracle VM. I got an error when I tested the memory and it saved this:
[image]

Is there a way to attach the error log? It's a long file

Comment: Please check if ISO file you used for installation is still mounted as virtual CD/DVD drive

Comment: @mrc02_kr Hello, do you mean the live CD/DVD box should be checked ?

Comment: When you start VM, open **Devices** menu, and **Optical drives** submenu, and click **Remove disc from virtual drive**

Comment: It won't start the VM. That's the problem

Comment: Ok actually, I managed to find the option and selected it and now the VM is completely black. It was already mounted

Comment: Okay, changing the boot order somehow fixed the issue for now.